# What are these wheel-chocks made of and what color do they most probably have?

Tags: aviation-history, wwii

I found a new hobby of mine: Colorizing black and white photos. My first project was a B-17 and now I'm working on a He 162 Volksjäger. The plane is on ground and fixed with wheel-chocks.

[image: He 162]

[image: Close up of the chocks]

Now the question is what they are made of and what color they could have. Maybe there is a specialist for german aviation in WWII out there.

Comment: Considering the shortage of metal, those are most likely made of wood.

Comment: The '6MU' on the chocks denotes #6 Maintenance Unit, Brize Norton.  He 162 #120086 was captured in 1945, displayed at Hyde Park in London and then moved to Brize for storage. And the chocks are almost certainly wooden. And, of course, the uniforms are RAF, not Luftwaffe!

Comment: Wait, that means this picture is made in England, not in Germany? You're really helping me out with your comment, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Noah: Indeed, England. There is more history here: http://captured-wings.wikia.com/wiki/Werk_Nr_120086 and  https://documents.techno-science.ca/documents/CASM-Aircrafthistories-HeinkelHe162A-2Volksjager.pdf

Comment: @Dave Great, great, great! Thanks!

Comment: You realize that photograph is [already in color](http://calvin-and-hobbes-comic-strips.blogspot.com/2011/11/calvin-asks-dad-about-old-black-and.html?m=1) don't you?

Comment: I thought that color was a post-war invention :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those chocks were made out of wood; I am guessing that they were unpainted or painted a bright color, for visibility. Today, they are made out of rubber or a synthetic. Rubber grips better than wood, but the wood chocks were most likely made out of wood, to preserve the rubber for the war effort.